Class that inherits from sf::Drawable cannot be use with std::vector
I use the SFML graphic framework to make a very small 2D game engine. Recently, I tried to convert the engine from a static library to a dynamic library, but a problem occurs.
It seems like a class that inherits from sf::Drawable cannot be used in std::vector.
Here is an small example:
Test.h
#pragma once

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class __declspec(dllexport) Entity : sf::Transformable, sf::Drawable
{
public:
    Entity()
    {
    };

    ~Entity()
    {
    };

public:
    std::vector<Entity> children;
};

Test.cpp
#include "Test.h"

Error

error C2672: 'std::construct_at': no matching overloaded function found

Complete building output
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\include\xmemory(698,14): error C2672: 'std::construct_at': no matching overloaded function found
1>(compiling source file '/Window.cpp')
1>    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\include\xutility(388,16):
1>    could be '_Ty *std::construct_at(_Ty *const ,_Types ...) noexcept(<expr>)'
1>    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\include\xmemory(698,14):
1>    the template instantiation context (the oldest one first) is
1>        C:\Users\jehud\source\repos\Harmony\Harmony\Test.h(19,22):
1>        see reference to class template instantiation 'std::vector<Entity,std::allocator<Entity>>' being compiled
1>        C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\include\vector(1476,26):
1>        while compiling class template member function 'std::vector<Entity,std::allocator<Entity>> &std::vector<Entity,std::allocator<Entity>>::operator =(const std::vector<Entity,std::allocator<Entity>> &)'
1>            C:\Users\jehud\source\repos\Harmony\Harmony\Test.h(20,1):
1>            see the first reference to 'std::vector<Entity,std::allocator<Entity>>::operator =' in 'Entity::operator ='
1>        C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\include\vector(1492,9):
1>        see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::vector<Entity,std::allocator<Entity>>::_Assign_counted_range<Entity*>(_Iter,const unsigned __int64)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Iter=Entity *
1>        ]
1>        C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\include\vector(1395,32):
1>        see reference to function template instantiation 'Entity *std::_Uninitialized_copy_n<Entity*,std::allocator<Entity>>(_InIt,size_t,Entity *,_Alloc &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _InIt=Entity *,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<Entity>
1>        ]
1>        C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\include\xmemory(1865,18):
1>        see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Uninitialized_backout_al<std::allocator<Entity>>::_Emplace_back<Entity&>(Entity &)' being compiled
1>        C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\include\xmemory(1779,35):
1>        see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Default_allocator_traits<_Alloc>::construct<_Ty,Entity&>(_Alloc &,_Objty *const ,Entity &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<Entity>,
1>            _Ty=Entity,
1>            _Objty=Entity
1>        ]

It works well when built as a static library without the __declspec(dllexport), but for some unknown reason to me it won't with the __declspec(dllexport).

Learn about the rule of 3/5/0 (you provided one constructor so you have to provide . And it could well be that the baseclasses are not default or move constructilble. Also when designing software, you should limit the number of dependencies you "leak" out of your dll (e.g. all your dependencies on SFML). E.g give you class an abstract base class and only export a facory method for that abstract baseclass.

I can't reproduce this error.  Your code compiles for me.

@DrewDormann Even when you compile it as an dynamic library?

That wouldn't change whether a matching overloaded function exists.  I believe your issue is not where you're looking.

I think your problem is
Exporting classes containing `std::` objects (vector, map etc.) from a DLL
The vector used inside of the DLL may not be the same as on the outside, even if the definition looks the same.
Also the inside could use a completely different STL.
When you link statically then you can be sure that everything uses the same definitions.
The "S" in STL may not be so Standard as you think it should be.
